# Get value of object using key that belong through

Tags: php, database, laravel

I build a web site that displays server specifications and features:

The main objects is:
Category:
Expressing the class of servers ("shared servers", "cloud servers")
The category contains packages (plans) and all packages in a class have the same features but different in values.
The category also contains several services and several FAQs.

Package:
Containing packages (plans) such as ("Business Plan", "Unlimited Plan", "Work Plane")
All packages have the same form but differ in values for common features.

The administrator can create the class template and add the features available in this category, and then add packages in this category.

I created this database design (image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngPKb.png)

Keys Features Model

```
class HostingFeatureKey extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hosting_feature_keys';

    public function feature_values()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\HostingPackageHasFeatureValue',
            'App\HostingCategoryHasFeatureKey',
            'feature_key_id',
            'category_has_feature_key_id',
            'id',
            'id'
        );
    }

    public function feature_value_of(HostingPackage $package)
    {
        return $this->feature_values()->get()->where('package_id', $package->id)->first();
    }
}
```

- The function "feature_value_of" works correctly

Package Model

```
class HostingPackage extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hosting_packages';


    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\HostingCategory', 'category_id');
    }

    public function icon()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\HostingIcon', 'icon_id');
    }

    public function feature_values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\HostingPackageHasFeatureValue', 'package_id', 'id');
    }

    public function feature_value_of(HostingFeatureKey $feature_key)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

How do I implement "feature_value_of" function in HostingPackage model to return the value of "feature_key" key for this object as "feature_value_of" function in HostingFeatureKey model.